# Jmeter Beanshell ---- finding Highest number from the response

Tags: jmeter

Below is the response:

```
    <div class="input radio_buttons optional challenger_order_selected"><span class="radio"><input class="radio_buttons optional" id="challenger_order_selected_eulcrnhkvss5r0tqtg5obeziwwewdz09ls1usjdodytuditqdmnowe5lskzpmdvbpt0--3fb112e512edd2f77187705cbefeb5c479c85a80" name="challenger[order_selected]" type="radio" value="eUlCRnhkVSs5R0tqTG5obEZIWWEwdz09LS1USjdOdytuditQdmNoWE5LSkZpMDVBPT0=--3fb112e512edd2f77187705cbefeb5c479c85a80" /><label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="challenger_order_selected_eulcrnhkvss5r0tqtg5obeziwwewdz09ls1usjdodytuditqdmnowe5lskzpmdvbpt0--3fb112e512edd2f77187705cbefeb5c479c85a80">54</label></span></div>
<div class="input radio_buttons optional challenger_order_selected"><span class="radio"><input class="radio_buttons optional" id="challenger_order_selected_dennu2ewd3dptc8wl08ya0tkblhtzz09ls1ime5hqw5yenvfmjjdmfkyk3fzse53pt0--12dc0d52ba07f91b2957ce4a64aca7c812087239" name="challenger[order_selected]" type="radio" value="dENnU2Ewd3dpTC8wL08ya0tkblhTZz09LS1IME5hQW5yenVFMjJDMFkyK3FzSE53PT0=--12dc0d52ba07f91b2957ce4a64aca7c812087239" /><label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="challenger_order_selected_dennu2ewd3dptc8wl08ya0tkblhtzz09ls1ime5hqw5yenvfmjjdmfkyk3fzse53pt0--12dc0d52ba07f91b2957ce4a64aca7c812087239">53</label></span></div>
<div class="input radio_buttons optional challenger_order_selected"><span class="radio"><input class="radio_buttons optional" id="challenger_order_selected_zc91djdxcxc3oxflazgvahqxnvbyzz09ls1mcxvtrfp1dtrfuu1jyuntrwpvcuznpt0--004c87cba6be163627a29ecf097145307e875ff0" name="challenger[order_selected]" type="radio" value="ZC91djdXcXc3OXFlazgvaHQxNVBYZz09LS1McXVTRFp1dTRFUU1jYUNtRWpVcUZnPT0=--004c87cba6be163627a29ecf097145307e875ff0" /><label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="challenger_order_selected_zc91djdxcxc3oxflazgvahqxnvbyzz09ls1mcxvtrfp1dtrfuu1jyuntrwpvcuznpt0--004c87cba6be163627a29ecf097145307e875ff0">20</label></span></div>
<div class="input radio_buttons optional challenger_order_selected"><span class="radio"><input class="radio_buttons optional" id="challenger_order_selected_djvlznvtuytgvhhpn1iybnpob1nwut09ls1zwtvfl2vprfe0awdkkzbnwhlcumxrpt0--a3d2052afedd2987a5e31cfb11996ed7b9bb28e5" name="challenger[order_selected]" type="radio" value="djVLZnVtUytGVHhPN1IybnpOb1NWUT09LS1ZWTVFL2VPRFE0aWdKKzBnWHlCUmxRPT0=--a3d2052afedd2987a5e31cfb11996ed7b9bb28e5" /><label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="challenger_order_selected_djvlznvtuytgvhhpn1iybnpob1nwut09ls1zwtvfl2vprfe0awdkkzbnwhlcumxrpt0--a3d2052afedd2987a5e31cfb11996ed7b9bb28e5">244</label></span></div>
<div class="input radio_buttons optional challenger_order_selected"><span class="radio"><input class="radio_buttons optional" id="challenger_order_selected_shbjtuz1ajz5c0xuqxfuutl0bzzwut09ls1iexj0svdlnuzbzhjta2oryvg4utvbpt0--4bcb59d227c1658800f0c2a4d9ca70c59b002d22" name="challenger[order_selected]" type="radio" value="SHBjTUZ1ajZ5c0xuQXFUUTl0bzZWUT09LS1IeXJ0SVdlNUZBZHJTa2orYVg4UTVBPT0=--4bcb59d227c1658800f0c2a4d9ca70c59b002d22" /><label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="challenger_order_selected_shbjtuz1ajz5c0xuqxfuutl0bzzwut09ls1iexj0svdlnuzbzhjta2oryvg4utvbpt0--4bcb59d227c1658800f0c2a4d9ca70c59b002d22">101</label></span></div>
```

i need to find the highest number from the list that is 244 and the respective dynamic value also that is "djVLZnVtUytGVHhPN1IybnpOb1NWUT09LS1ZWTVFL2VPRFE0aWdKKzBnWHlCUmxRPT0=--a3d2052afedd2987a5e31cfb11996ed7b9bb28e5".
can you please help me how to write bean-shell for the same

Comment: look up jmeter xpath extractor.

Comment: My question is like i need to find the highest number from the list.. after doing the regular expression and the respective dynamic value..

Answer (score 1):

You can use [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) to:

1. Identify the label with the largest value
2. Get "value" attribute of the relevant input
3. Both points 1 and 2 can be done in a single expression

**Example** XPath expression which does above will look like:

```
//div/span/label[not(text() <= ../../preceding-sibling::div/span/label/text()) and not(text() <=../../following-sibling::div/span/label/text())]/../input/@value
```

**Disclaimer**: above expression will work only against response data mentioned in your question, if your actual response has different markup - it might not be accurate.

**Evidence**:

[image: XPath Extractor Evidence]

**Warning**: the XPath expression is very memory and resource intensive, use it wisely.

**References**:

- [XPath 1.0 Language Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)
- [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp)
- [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, the values changes for each run.. so what i was thinking is need to find all the values from the list keeping match = -1. find the match_Nr.. find the greatest value and the position of the value so that i can get the dynamic value related to the highest value... but i want the beanshell for the same

Comment: Above approach will work for any number of values, @v0devil provided beanshell option

Answer (score -1):

Put it in beanshell postprocessor:

```
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    String response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<div class=\"input radio_buttons optional challenger_order_selected\"><span class=\"radio\"><input class=\"radio_buttons optional\" id=\".+?\" name=\"challenger[order_selected]\" type=\"radio\" value=\"(.+?)\" /><label class=\"collection_radio_buttons\" for=\".+?\">(\d+?)</label></span></div>");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(response);

    Integer maxLabel, curLabel = 0;
    String value = "";
    while (matcher.find()) 
    {
       curLabel = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(2));
       if(curLabel>maxLabel)
    {
    maxLabel=curLabel;   
    value = matcher.group(1);
    }
    }

    vars.put("value", value);
```